# MacOS hangs when connected to a wifi network with no internet

Tags: macos, network, internet

I'm running Catalina 10.15.7, and have noticed that whilst connected to my new wifi router (that hasn't been set up with internet yet), launching programs or just trying to use the system causes programs to hang, and applications to not respond.

It has also caused applications that monitor input control (better touch tool) to make external keyboard and mouse inputs not respond.